# Will a NEMA L5-20P plug work in a NEMA L5-30R receptacle?

Tags: ups, power-distribution-unit, apc-smart-ups

I need to purchase a UPS & PDU and want to know if they will be compatible.  Will the plug of the PDU be able to plug into this UPS?

The UPS: [APC Smart-UPS X 3000VA Rack/Tower LCD 100-127V with Network Card](http://www.apc.com/products/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=SMX3000RMLV2UNC)

The PDU: [Rack PDU, Basic, Zero U, 20A, 120V, (14)5-15](http://www.apc.com/products/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=AP9551)

**Edit**

I will be running two 2U servers as well as 5 disk arrays with a combined total of 63 15k SAS drives.  Each unit has redundant power.  I plan on having one power cable go to each UPS.  Will a 15A PDU be enough to carry this load?

**2nd Edit**

Also, where can I buy power cables in a different color, other than black?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should *not* use a 20 amp plug on a circuit that is 30 amps.  The connectors are designed to prevent you from mixing amperages this way.  You should buy a 30 amp PDU if you are going to use a 30 amp UPS. Do *not* buy an adapter.

Mixing the two can cause a fire and is likely a violation of local electrical code and fire law.

Edit:

daveM is correct.  But remember that you should only load a circuit to 80% of its capacity, or you can cause it to blow when all of the servers reset at the same time after a power outage. Also watch out for exceeding the BTU/sq. ft requirements of the cooling in your area.

Answer (score 2):

The sockets/connectors are different APC should have a variant of the PDU or the UPS that will be compatible.  A call or E-mail to APC will get you the info you require quickly.

As to the load, APC has excellent tools to calculate this. [UPS Selector](http://www.apc.com/tools/ups_selector/index.cfm)  Using this tool you can usually determine if what you are planning will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can step up or down... depending on how many sockets you need.

Using the Nema 5-15:
http://www.apc.com/products/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=AP9567

Using the Nema 5-30:
http://www.apc.com/products/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=AP7532

Comment: I only have 24U to work with.  How much load can a 15A PDU take? I edited the question to include the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

A L5-30R (receptacle) circuit is rated for 30Amps, putting a 20Amp load (L5-20P Plug) on it is withing the design capacity.

The reverse is not true.  Plugging L5-30P (30A Plug) into an L5-20R (Receptacle) is NOT ok and would exceed the amperage rating for the circuit. Also it won't fit.